# Exposing Docker Container Ports

Tags: network-programming, docker, ports

I understand that to expose ports in a docker container, you can use the `-p` flag (e.g. `-p 1-100:1-100`). But is there a nice way to expose a large percentage of possible ports from the container to the host machine? For instance if I am running a router of sorts in a container that lives in a VM, and I would like to expose all ports in the container from 32768 upwards to 65535, is there a nice way to do this? As it stands I've tried using the `-p` flag and it complains about memory allocation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm. I figured out my misunderstanding. `-P` is what I want, and I want to expose and not explicitly map ports.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr

```
docker run --net=host ...
```

---

Docker offers different networking modes for containers. By default the networking mode is [`bridge`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#mode-bridge) which implies the need to expose ports.

If you run a container with networking mode [`host`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#mode-host) then you won't need to expose/forward ports as both the docker host and the container will share the very same network interface.

In the container, `localhost` will refer to the docker host. Any port opened in the container is in fact opened on the docker host network interface.