# bind docker containers services start on the specific port

Tags: docker

I have running multiple application running inside a container like apache,tomcat,elasticsearch etc and committed as a new image. (i hvn't use dockerfile)

I can able to start the all the application from host using **`docker run with /bin/sh -c /run.sh`** but i don't know how to expose the all services port number to host, so i can able to access the services from host machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exposing Docker Container Ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900926/exposing-docker-container-ports)

Comment: this is quite similar question but start services inside container and solving scenario is little different. Thanks for acknowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Your container with

```
docker run -p host_port:container_port
```

To expose multiple ports, simply provide multiple -p arguments:

```
docker run -p host_port1:container_port1 -p host_port2:container_port2 **image_name** /bin/sh -c /run.sh
```

where **/run.sh** file contains the startup script inside the **image** at / which start the service manually.
(In my case my application was not getting start by image_bootup so i achieve this using script)

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [docker command line reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) you can use the `-p` flag to expose specific ports when running a container.

The Docker site states:

> Note: The -p flag can be used multiple times to configure multiple ports.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Comment: But I have multiple port running and also some application which use random port number so how can I expose them using -p flag, and I havnt use dockerfile so is there possibility to expose entire container port over host ?

Comment: @anand You could consider using host networking. Defeats some of isolation benefits of using Docker.

Comment: @mark sir but while using host networking few  problem I get like "su user" is not working inside the container and also found my hadoop is failed to start due to --net=host but everything goes right with bridge networking